# How to know what the location.host is from within a Nuxt.js middleware property

Tags: nuxt.js

Is it possible to know what the location.host is on the server thru the middleware property in Nuxt.js?

https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware#the-middleware-property

In other words, if I navigate to http://www.example.com, how can i have access to the 'www.mysite.com' segment of the url.

I can't seem to find the equivalent of windows.location.host for the server that works in the middleware on the server.  I have access to the context object, but can't seem to find a way to access the host property or even know if it is available.  Same with the request object.  Is it available within nuxt middleware?

if (process.server) {

// windows.location.host <- this doesn't work here because we are on the server.

}

My question seems to be similar to this one that nobody has answered.
[Get current domain name from request in Nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854595/get-current-domain-name-from-request-in-nuxt)

thank you